# Why custom 404 page doesn't work in Next.js 13?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, custom-error-pages

In next 13, I'm trying to use custom 404 page, using this method: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/not-found. But when I write unmatched URL I see the empty page!

This is my custom 404 page:

```
"use client"
import React,{useEffect} from 'react'


 const NotFound = () => {
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("not found")
  },[])
  return (
    <>
<div>not found</div>
    </>
  )
}
export default NotFound
```

And this is my folder structure:

[image: structure]

And this is the layout for not-found (layout.tsx):

```
  return (
    <>
    
      <main className="px-10 py-5 ">
    
        {children}
       
     </main>
    
    </>
  )
```

I can see   console.log("not found") result In my browser, but I can't see the `<div>Not found</div>`  in my browser (It also doesn't show in inspector).

Comment: Have tried without the `useEffect`. In my case, when it's there, it's throwing an error.

Comment: Could you please specify the exact version of Next.js 13 that you used to create your project?

Comment: @BhartiSharma it is 14.1

Comment: Please try, Temporarily removing the layout component to see if it's causing any issues with rendering the custom 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was I had forgotten add html and body tag to the layout for not-found(I added the wrong layout to updated question). In my layout.tsx I added html and body tag and it works. This is my new layout.tsx:

```
  return (
    <>
     <html lang="en" className="h-full w-full" >
      <body className="h-full w-full">
      <main className="px-10 py-5 ">
    
        {children}
       
     </main>
        </body>
     </html>
    </>
  )
```

Comment: Great it solve your issue but you should know that the custom 404 page in Next.js is a special page that is shown when a user navigates to a route that does not exist. It is independent of your layout component and will be displayed regardless of the layout structure you have defined.